# Apipie for documentation not work for nested namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

Using [APipie](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails) for API docuemnation for rails app and it work perfect, but when try to use nested namespace its not showing up the doc for this controllers inside the namespace for example:

this one work ok:

```
scope 'api', module: :api, constraints: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :missions do
      resources :tasks        
    end
  end
end
```

but this one not:

```
scope 'api', module: :api, constraints: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    namespace :counselor do
      resources :students
    end
  end
end
```

any clue why Apipie not show docs for this nested namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem:

in my `apipie.rb` for APipie configuration `api_controller_matcher` was set like this:

```
config.api_controllers_matcher = "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/api/v1/*.rb"
```

changed to be

```
config.api_controllers_matcher = File.join(Rails.root, "app", "controllers", "api", "v1", "**","*.rb")
```

now it can see all controllers and its routes.